# TextInputEditText - Make clickable but not editable

Tags: android, layout, material-ui, material-components-android

I have a layout where I want to show a bunvh of edit texts and a date picker. Since I want to have the same design for all fields, I figured out that I need to user an edit text for date picker too but make it non editable but clickable. Below is the xml code of my edit text that will be used to show the date picker :

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/notification_layout"
    style="@style/Theme.Connect.InputFieldLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_stk_notification_24dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/notification_edit_text"
        style="@style/Theme.Connect.InputField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Notification"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:lines="1"
        android:cursorVisible="false"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I tried many solutions I found on the internet, I did managed to make edit text non editable but without the ripple click effect. Is there a way to make the edit text non edditable but still keep the ripple click effect? Is this the best practice to show a date picker consisting the design of the form layout?

Answer (score 3):

```
 Try this and change the `android:focusable` attribute to `false`                       


<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
      android:id="@+id/notification_layout"
       style="@style/Theme.Connect.InputFieldLayout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_stk_notification_24dp">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/notification_edit_text"
    style="@style/Theme.Connect.InputField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Notification"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:lines="1"
    android:cursorVisible="false"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Tries you answer and I still can not achieve ripple effect as a usual MaterialAutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: if you can send a sample of what you want to do, that will be more helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a `TextView` instead of an `EditText` and you can set an `onClickListener()` to it. You can also style it the way you want.

```kotlin
notification_textview.setOnClickListener {
    // Whatever you want to do after a click
}
```

You can get a ripple effect on touch by adding these 2 attributes to your textview

```
<......Textview
android:background=?android:attr/selectableItemBackground
android:clickable="true" />
```

You can also add styles to a textview that you wanted to use for the `editText`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I use a text view, I will end up with different design fields. Also, text view will not have a ripple click effect, Right?

Comment: @George You can use a custom style for the textview, you'll have to do a bit of more research to do this,

Comment: used `android:background=?android:attr/selectableItemBackground` inside TextInputEditText, got ripple effect. Thanks.